# How to get the data for all elements not only for the first one

Tags: javascript, custom-data-attribute

I am now a few hours on a problem that I cant solve.

I have a button with few data attributes,  the button opens a js modal. The data of the data attributes needs to show in the modal.
**This button is also printed out like 15 times via a php foreach and every button has some other data.**

```html
<div class='w-full sm:w-full md:w-full lg:w-1/4 xl:w-1/5 float-left'>
 <div class='ml-2 mr-2 p-4 bg-white rounded h-auto mt-2'>
  <center>
  <center><div class='h-16 w-16'><img src='$img_url'></div><center>
  <p class='pb-1 text-xl'><span class='font-bold'>$currency_name</span>
  <span class='text-sm'>$currency_code</span></p>
  <p class='pb-2'><span class='text-center'>$balance</span></p>
  <p class='flex items-center justify-between mb-0 border-b-2 border-t-2 border gray-300'>
  <span class='text-left'>Price: </span><span class='text-right'>$price</span></p>
  <p class='flex items-center justify-between mb-0 border-b-2 border-gray-300'> 
  <span class='text-left'>Fee: </span><span class='text-right'>$payout_fee</span> 
 </p>
</center>
<div class=''>
<button class='mt-2 bg-transparent hover:bg-blue-500 text-blue-700 font-semibold hover:text-white py-2 px-4 border border-blue-500 hover:border-transparent rounded my-button withdraw' data-currency_name='$currency_name' data-currency_code='$currency_code'>Withdraw</button></div>
</div></div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var currency_name = $('.withdraw').data('currency_name');

    document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = "Withdraw "+currency_name+"";

  });
  
  </script>
```

The problem now is that only the first button prints the right info. All other ones giving out the data of the first one. **my-button class is for the modal.**

Maybe one of you has an idea?

Comment: `data currency_code` needs a dash.. `data-currency_code`. Maybe this?

Comment: You will probably need to loop through each button with the `my-button` class.

Comment: Thanks for this! But that is only a fail in this post. In my code it has a slash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to get the data attributes of every element with the `withdraw` class, then try out this:

```js
var buttons = $('.withdraw');

for(var i=0; i< buttons.length; i++){
    var button = $(`.withdraw:nth-child(${i+1})`);
    button.click(function() {
        var currency_name = $(this)[0].getAttribute("data-currency_name");
        $("#title")[0].innerHTML = `Withdraw ${currency_name}`;
    })
}
```

The `currencies` variable is an array, which will contain all of the currency values.

What does `document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = "Withdraw "+currency_name+"";` do though? If you could give us a little bit more context to what you're trying to achieve, then I could give you a better script.

Comment: Hi Nanoo, every button is in a container with some styling and some infos about the currency and how much the user has of that currency. Now I want to make my site more dynamic and want to use javascript. After the user clicks on the button a modal pops up and shows as title the name of the currency (currency_name).

Comment: Alright, I have an idea. Any chance you could edit your post, so it contains an example with the button container?

Comment: Sure, I will do! Btw I use the css framework tailwind.

Comment: I edited my script, so now when you click on the button, it changes the modal title to the button's currency name.

Comment: No problem. Just a quick tip: if you're only changing the text when using `innerHTML`, then you can just use `innerText`.

Comment: But there isn't really much difference.

Comment: I will add more. But thanks for that info. I will definitely learn more about javascript :D